# Dropped connection, when modem heats up?

Tags: modem

Can it be a factor? I have a 24 Mbps line, and around 12 computers connected to the modem using 2 switches, and no cooling. Its India, and summer. I lose connection every 10 minutes. The DSL light is on constantly, and I have tried 3 different modems, including complaints to the ISP (BSNL, in case you ask), to check the line quality. Is temperature a factor for dropped connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be. It's not unusual hardware reboots/shuts down if it gets too warm (as a safety precaution).

If your router gets too warm and reboots, it'll drop all connections (and most probably it'll be offline for short time).

Comment: +1 - temperature is a factor with any and all hardware, period, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Definate issue.  Are the switches and modem stacked?  Often see this issue in Canada when modem is stacked on router and/or on switch.  Heat rises and something stops working.

One other possibility.  Are the devices on a UPS?  Have seen brownout send a modem or router into a "hung" state.